# How to take only last emitted value for each second

Tags: rxjs

The use case is that I've got an observable that emits a value with a very high frequency. I use the value to update the view, so I'd like to subscribe to the observable and take a last emitted value each second (to update the view only once per second) - so to debounce the stream for a second, take latest value, debounce for the next second, take next latest value, and so on.

Comment: Share what you have up till now - SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 2):

You can use `throttleTime` operator (see https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttletime):

```
// emits 10 times per second
const source = interval(100);

// emits once every second
const example = source.pipe(throttleTime(1000));
```

**edit after feedback in comment**

```
const example = merge(
  source.pipe(
    throttleTime(1000)
  ), 
  source.pipe(
    last()
  )
);
```

Comment: Not exactly, because I need to take the latest value, not next which will be emittem.

Comment: what exactly is the difference between the latest value and the next one which will be emitted? How should we determine when to set the 'reference window'?

Comment: The difference is that it should behave similar to debounce, the last value might be emitted before the second last, so it will be lost then

Comment: When you are talking about "last value", does this mean that the source observable is completed somewhen and in any case you always want to get the latest value emitted?

Comment: Have a look at `auditTime()` and `sampleTime()`. Maybe one of them is what you're looking for

Comment: that's a good hint. Maybe you can provide an answer yourself. sampleTime seems to be exactly what he's looking for and I don't want to take credit for something I didn't know before.